# Como adicionar uma classe de CSS a imagens que não carregaram?

Tags: jquery, css, imagem

Tenho uma página de HTML com inúmeras imagens apresentadas da seguinte forma:

```html
<img alt="img1" width="50" height="120" src="my_image.jpg" />
<img alt="img2" width="50" height="120" src="another_image.jpg" />
<img alt="img3" width="50" height="120" src="yet_another_image.jpg" />
```

Se alguma das imagens não carregar por motivo A ou B, vão existir quebras no layout ou em alguns navegadores, vai aparecer o quadrado da imagem com o texto alternativo, tornado todo o aspecto um bocadinho feio.

## Pergunta

Como posso através de jQuery adicionar uma classe de CSS às imagens cuja acção de carregar a mesma falhou ?

**Exemplo:**

```html
<img alt="img1" width="50" height="120" src="my_image.jpg" class="failToLoad" />
```

Comment: Se a imagem for externa (e.g. imgur) com uma url inválida a imagem não irá gerar error 404, portanto soluções utilizando o evento `error` podem não contemplar todos casos.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A maneira mais "natural" seria usar o `onerror` (jQuery: [`error`](http://api.jquery.com/error/)), mas é preciso cuidado pois esse evento somente será capturado se ele ocorrer **depois** que o *handler* já tiver sido adicionado. Por isso, uma solução seria colocar o script que adiciona a classe no princípio do documento (`head`, ou início do `body` - antes de qualquer `img`). Para não ficar muito pesado, uma solução **sem** jQuery:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function erro(elemento) { 
    elemento.className += ' failToLoad'; // Adiciona a classe às já existentes, se houver
}
</script>
...
<img src="..." onerror="erro(this)" />
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85kZQ/4/).

Uma maneira alternativa, baseada [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/93017/520779) no SO em inglês, parece funcionar corretamente caso seja necessário colocar o JavaScript no final (no `onLoad` do documento, por exemplo).

```javascript
$('img').each(function() {
    if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('failToLoad');
    }
});
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/85kZQ/). A vantagem desse técnica é que não é necessário qualquer alteração nas tags HTML.

Comment: Vale observar que o exemplo no jsFiddle esta rodando no evento `onLoad`. Para este código funcionar ele deve estar depois de todos elementos `img` ou em um dos eventos: `DOMContentLoaded` ou `Load`

Comment: Alias, testando mais eu notei que a segunda alternativa só funciona no evento `load`. Pois se as imagens não estiverem em cache a propriedade `complete` nem sempre será `true`.

Comment: @BrunoLM Verdade, isso também me ocorreu quando vi o código pela primeira vez. Imagino que, das três uma: 1) o `complete` já estará pronto quando o script executar; 2) o `load` da imagem vai executar (dando a chance de limpar a classe); 3) o `error` da imagem vai executar. De modo que a primeira alternativa me parece mais confiável IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode atribuir um evento de `error` nas imagens desejadas e adicionar a classe `failToLoad`

#### Exemplo

```javascript
$("#falha")
.on('error',function(){
   $(this).addClass('failToLoad');
   console.log('Essa imagem nao carregou');
})
.attr('src','falha.png');
```

**Lembrando que você não pode recuperar o erro após a imagem e o DOM serem carregados**, já que o browser já irá ter propagado o evento de *erro ao carregar a imagem*, por isso você deve inserir o `src` após anexar o evento nela.

Essa dificuldade é destacada na API do jQuery **[.error()](http://api.jquery.com/error/)**

**[Exemplo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DKR8t/)**

#### Solução

Uma solução automática seria utilizar as tags `data-*`

HTML

```html
<img data-src="falha.png">
```

JavaScript

```javascript
//Para cada <img> da página
$('img').each(function(){
    //Selecionar essa imagem
    $(this)
    //Atribuir o evento de erro
    .on('error', function(){
        //Caso ocorra o erro, adicionar a classe failToLoad
        $(this).addClass('failToLoad');
    })
    //Definir o src da imagem recuperando do atributo data-src
    .attr('src',$(this).data('src'));
});
```

Assim, todas as suas imagens que tiverem erro ao carregar, automaticamente irão ganhar a classe `failToLoad`

**[Solução JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DKR8t/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Para novos elementos inseridos dinamicamente é possível fazer utilizando [o `MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). E para as demais imagens basta obtê-las e adicionar o evento.

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(
    function(mutations) 
    {
        for (var m in mutations)
        {
            var mutation = mutations[m];

            if (mutation.addedNodes) // todos nodos adicionados
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; ++i)
                {
                    var node = mutation.addedNodes[i];

                    if (node.nodeName == "IMG") // se for imagem
                    {
                        // adiciona o evento "error"
                        // caso o erro ocorra, a classe será adicionada
                        node.addEventListener("error", function() {
                            node.className += " failToLoad";
                        }, false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
);

// inicia o observer
observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

E para os elementos já existentes na página:

```js
$(function() { // quando a página carregar o DOM

    // para todas imagens da página
    $("img").each(function(i,e) {

        // adiciona o evento
        e.addEventListener("error", function(imgEvents) {
            var img = e;

            e.className += " failToLoad"; // em caso de erro adiciona classe

        }, false);

    });
});
```

Veja este [exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G2a47/). Note que imagens inseridas dinamicamente também são validadas. Neste exemplo o script está sendo inserido entre a tag `<head>`.

Note que se a imagem for externa, por exemplo o imgur, e você passar um link inválido o site não irá gerar o erro 404 ao invés disso ele ira gerar uma imagem padrão.

[image: imagem de erro do imgur]